# MySQL: UPDATE field with JOIN

Tags: mysql

TLDR: Fixed, was using `max_ram`, in stead of `ram_max`, I'm an idiot.

I'd like to update the contents op the fields in column `ram_max` to `DDR3 ECC VLP`:

```
MariaDB [intnetro_sept4test]> SELECT server_ram.server_id, server.brandtype, server_ram.ram_max  
    ->   FROM  server
    ->   JOIN  server_ram ON server_ram.server_id = server.id
    -> WHERE 
    ->     server.brandtype = 'Microcloud (X10SLE-F)' 
    ->     AND server_ram.ram_max LIKE '%Registered%'
    -> LIMIT 10;
+-----------+-----------------------+-------------------------+
| server_id | brandtype             | ram_max                 |
+-----------+-----------------------+-------------------------+
|       877 | Microcloud (X10SLE-F) | DDR3 ECC Registered VLP |
|       877 | Microcloud (X10SLE-F) | DDR3 ECC Registered VLP |
|       898 | Microcloud (X10SLE-F) | DDR3 Registered VLP     |
|       898 | Microcloud (X10SLE-F) | DDR3 Registered VLP     |
|       899 | Microcloud (X10SLE-F) | DDR3 ECC Registered VLP |
|       899 | Microcloud (X10SLE-F) | DDR3 ECC Registered VLP |
+-----------+-----------------------+-------------------------
```

I was able to figure I should do something like:

```
UPDATE server_ram
INNER JOIN server
    SET server_ram.max_ram = ECC
    WHERE
    server.brandtype = "Microcloud (X10SLE-F)"
    AND server_ram.ram_max LIKE "%Registered%";
```

But when executing I get:

```
MariaDB [intnetro_sept4test]> UPDATE server_ram
    -> INNER JOIN server
    ->     SET server_ram.max_ram = DDR3 ECC VLP
    ->     WHERE
    ->     server.brandtype = "Microcloud (X10SLE-F)"
    ->     AND server_ram.ram_max LIKE "%Registered%";
ERROR 1054 (42S22): Unknown column 'server_ram.max_ram' in 'field list'
```

So how do I properly `JOIN` a table in an `UPDATE` query?

Example of `sever_ram` table:

```
MariaDB [intnetro_sept4test]> SELECT * FROM `server_ram` WHERE `server_id` = 655
   -> ;
+------+-----------+----------+---------------------+---------------+------+
| id   | server_id | ram_size | ram_max             | ram_available | type |
+------+-----------+----------+---------------------+---------------+------+
| 2091 |       655 | 8192     | DDR3 ECC Registered | 0             |      |
| 2092 |       655 | 8192     | DDR3 ECC Registered | 0             |      |
| 2093 |       655 | 8192     | DDR3 ECC Registered | 0             |      |
| 2094 |       655 | 8192     | DDR3 ECC Registered | 0             |      |
+------+-----------+----------+---------------------+---------------+------+
```

Example of `server` table:

```
MariaDB [intnetro_sept4test]> SELECT * FROM `server` WHERE `id` = 655;
+-----+--------------+----------------+------------------+--------------------+------------+------------+------------------+------+------+--------------------+-------------------+---------+--------+-----------------+-----------------+-----------------+--------------+--------------+--------+---------+-----------+-----+------+----------+-----------------------------------+------------+---------------+---------------+---------------+------------------+------------------+------------+-------------------------------------------------+-----------------+------------------------+
| id  | provisioning | provisioningos | lastprovisioning | name               | clientname | brand      | brandtype        | rdns | type | server_relative_id | server_slot_place | rack_id | height | switch1_port_id | switch2_port_id | switch3_port_id | apc1_port_id | apc2_port_id | active | buydate | usagedate | bbu | raid | raidname | processor                         | servicetag | ipmi_username | ipmi_password | ipmi_ip       | ipmi_op_username | ipmi_op_password | addtonocps | notes                                           | user_product_id | available_to_resellers |
+-----+--------------+----------------+------------------+--------------------+------------+------------+------------------+------+------+--------------------+-------------------+---------+--------+-----------------+-----------------+-----------------+--------------+--------------+--------+---------+-----------+-----+------+----------+-----------------------------------+------------+---------------+---------------+---------------+------------------+------------------+------------+-------------------------------------------------+-----------------+------------------------+
| 655 | 0            |                |                0 | server.vghost2.com |            | Supermicro | FatTwin (X9DRFR) |      |    5 |                373 |                 0 |      52 |      1 |               0 |               0 |               0 |            0 |            0 |      0 |         |           |   1 |    0 |          | 2x Intel Xeon E5-2620 at 2.00 Ghz |            | ADMIN         | r5Avuc8u@PEsp | 10.228.211.12 | operator         | BrUynkz3         |          1 | FatTwin #11
HDD SLOT #1 BROKEN 22-11-2016 - Jim |           31507 |                      1 |
+-----+--------------+----------------+------------------+--------------------+------------+------------+------------------+------+------+--------------------+-------------------+---------+--------+-----------------+-----------------+-----------------+--------------+--------------+--------+---------+-----------+-----+------+----------+-----------------------------------+------------+---------------+---------------+---------------+------------------+------------------+------------+-------------------------------------------------+-----------------+------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Thank you very much in advance!
Using `mariadb-server-10.1` on a MySQL table.

Comment: The error message is quite clear. There is no `max_ram` column in your table. Correct the first query by replacing `server_ram.max_ram = ECC` with `server_ram.ram_max = ECC`

Comment: `max_ram` shouldn't it be `ram_max` in line `SET server_ram.max_ram = DDR3 ECC VLP`

Comment: Oh my god, I'm such an idiot. I honestly spend hours trying to figure out what the heck I did wrong... Thank you so much guys. I'll go sit in a corner now...

Comment: @JitendraSoftgrid I'm messing around a bit:

`MariaDB [intnetro_sept4test]> UPDATE server_ram
    -> INNER JOIN server
    ->   SET server_ram.ram_max = "CACACACA"
    ->   WHERE
    ->   server.brandtype = 'Microcloud (X10SLE-F)' AND server.brand = 'Supermicro';`

This changes everything, all records, not the ones that should match... Am I missing something?

Comment: Where is your `ON`  ?,  `JOIN` should have an `ON` condition.